# Create ext4 img in windows

Tags: windows, ext4

I am trying to create an automated android x86 installer for my friend. I am creating img with dd. But I cant format it ro ext4. I found e2fsprog on a form but cant find a valid exucatible. How can I format img in ext4 format.

Comment: If you are good in programming, you might download the source codes of `mkfs.ext4` and compile them using cygwin or mingw. It might be neccessary to modify the sources a bit so they work under Windows. However, this would only allow you to create an EMPTY file system image.

Comment: Compile gives error for libraries not available on windows

Comment: why don't just download a Linux distro and run?

Comment: I can but my friend can't. Anyway I found binaries in ext2 driver for windows

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "creating an automated android x86 installer".   Normally the Android system, user, etc., images are built using the Android build process as part of the AOSP build system.   This includes creating the ext4 image with the prepopulated contents of the Android system files.   AOSP also will create all of the binaries necessary to install those images, including formatting the user partition and setting it up correctly..

Comment: My friends wants to install primeos. He can't because primeos installer needs net frame 4.5 which is not available on win 7 out of the box